# Restarting a service on Network Change Android

Tags: android, service, tcp, connectivity

I know it's not possible to keep the same socket across network changes, but what is the easiest way to restart a service after a network change? I assume the best practice is to listen for a `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcast, but where would I put this code? Can a service kill itself and recreate itself from scratch so my TCP connection will restart too? Or do I have to put code into another service that kills the TCP service (if so, how do I find the running instance of the service to kill it?)

Thank you for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:
Kill your service just like you starting it.

In your broadcast receiver:

```
 stopService(new Intent(context, ServiceName.class));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I said. But how do you kill a service that you didn't start in the first place (you own it, but you don't have the intent that started it)

Comment: Thank you - does this work even if the intent had extras? I assume Android uses hashcodes to compare the intents (it depends on how intent's hashcode is computed - including extras or not.)

Comment: Hmm, i think it doesn`t matter. I think it works like this: 
1) Android receiving your intent in stopService
2) Looking for instance of "ServiceName" (I dunno if wecan start several services of one class, but I suppose we can`t)
3) Killing it